# not getting output for this R script code

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

This R script is not giving an output. 
Please help me out.
The R code is:

```
names = colnames(train)
for(i in 2:80)
{    
ggplot(train, aes_string(x = names[i])) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),
bins = 50,colour="black", fill="white") + geom_density(alpha=.2, fill= "#FF8C00")
}
```

The train data frame contains 1460 rows and 81 columns with every column being of numeric type.
The first column is Id so I started the loop from 2 to 80.
The console is not showing any error and no plotting also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a for loop, you have to explicitly call the `print` function.  Here is reproducible demonstration of this need to explicitly call it.

```
library(ggplot2)

# This will not give any output
for(i in 1:1){
  ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
}

# This will give output
for(i in 1:1){
  print(ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point())
}
```

Comment: @SaiKrushnaRath Great, if you get a chance please accept the answer.